# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Maven projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have 2 Maven projects in Eclipse (Project 'api' and Project 'otp'). Project 'api' uses some classes located in Project 'otp'. I added Project 'otp' in the build path below.

[image]

Now, in compile time, there are no errors thrown. But when I try to run the project, the following error occurs. Why is that? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: add maven dependency of project otp in project api

Answer (score 1):

You added the project, but you aren't picking up its dependencies the way you are when building from maven.

You should formalize the dependency in your maven project structure and use the eclipse maven plugin to import the project.